# What does a genre id "-1" mean?

Tags: deezer

At this moment, a search for `http://api.deezer.com/search/album?q=Big%20Sean%20Bounce%20Back`, will have some results with a `genre_id` or `-1`.

Is there a specific meaning to this 'id'?

Comment: Seems that the genre has not been correctly set to these tracks, we just have to fix that. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing! Do you mind writing an answer to the question when you feel it's right so I can answer it so it's closes the case correctly? ;-)

Comment: Actually, @Fred_Dzr, I'm curious, I've had genres coming out as french, and a quick (and not too thorough) search seems to indicate that those might be related to albums that appears as "-1" when I make the API call manually... If that can help you see through things on your end!

Comment: A bit more info: I cache the api cal resultsl a bit locally so I don't overload Deezer and I went to check of the result I had the genre given in French. One of the search I made returned for an album an id of "228" for the first result, "Spiritualité & religion". Doing the same search manually at the moment gives me a genre_id of "-1": http://api.deezer.com/search/album?q=I%20Want%20You,%20I%20Need%20You%20Chris%20Christian